# Error with javascript prototype

Tags: prototype, javascript

I have been working on a javascript library. Here is the code:

```
(function (window) {
        var regex = {
            Id : /^[#]\w+$/,
            Class : /^[.]\w+$/,     
            Tag : /^\w+$/,
            validSelector : /^([#]\w+|[.]\w+|\w+)$/
        },  
        tex = function(selector){
            //only some of the functions need to select an element
            //EX:
            // style: tex(selector).style(style);
            //one that would not need a selector is the random number function:
            // tex().random(from,to);
            if (selector){
                if (typeof selector === 'string'){
                    var valid = validSelector.test(selector);
                    if( valid ){
                        if(regex.Id.test(string)){ 
                            this = document.getElementById(selector);
                        }
                        if(regex.Class.test(string)){ 
                            this = document.getElementByClass(selector);
                        }
                        if(regex.Tag.test(string)){ 
                            this = document.getElementByTagName(selector);
                        }
                    }
                }else if(typeof selector === 'object'){
                    this = selector;
                }
                //this = document.querySelector(selector);
                // I could make a selector engine byt I only need basic css selectors.
            }
        },
        tex.prototype = {
            dit : function(){
                this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!'
            }
        };
        window.tex = tex;
})(window);
```

It all looks like good code until I try to use the library on my webpage. When I try to activate it I get an error that says, "Error: Unexpected token '.'" referring to the `tex.prototype` line:

```
},
tex.prototype = {
    dit : function(){
```

Does anyone know what the matter with my code is?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should write this prototype after declaring 'tex'?

```
    },
    tex.prototype = {
        dit : function(){
            this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!'
        }
    };
```

change to:

```
};
tex.prototype = {
    dit : function(){
        this.innerHTML = 'Hi?!?!?!'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {};  // right
var o.a = 1; // wrong
o.a = 1;     // right
```

Replace the comma :

```
};
tex.prototype = {
    dit : function(){
```

There might be another problem with `this = ...;` :

```
this = 1; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

It means that you're not allowed to set the `this` keyword.

Comment: Ok, but jQuery does it that way... And the error is a couple lines of code below that.

Comment: @TekiTech "but jQuery does it that way...". Are you sure? I have just checked the sources and found nothing about that.

Comment: I have been reviewing the jQuery code and yes, it does declare `this = element`

Comment: @TekiTech Which version? I checked this one : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js.

Comment: @TekiTech Same as mine... So, who's blind?

Comment: Yeah. In the `jQuery.init` it says `this.length = 1;this[0] = elem;`

Comment: @TekiTech `this[0] = elem;` is totally different than `this = elem;`. Your code will surely crash one day.

Comment: ?? How? I thought they were pretty much the same.

Comment: @TekiTech Have a look at my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a reply to our previous discussion, here is a quick revision :

```
var o;    // defines a new variable named "o"
o = {};   // sets the variable "o" as an empty object
o[0] = 1; // adds a property named "0" to this object
```

So, this code adds a new property to `this` :

```
this[0] = elem;
```

While this one crashes :

```
this = elem; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```